# Page numbers inside UIWebView when loading PDF

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

I am loading PDF file inside UIWebView (iOS7). Unfortunately I can not get page numbers to be displayed when I scroll PDF (see image). How I can do it?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that page numbers where hidden underneath the navigation bar (see picture with navigation bar hidden). Not sure why though, because the scroller ended perfectly underneath the navigation bar. My solution will be to hide navigation bar and show it only when user taps or scrolls up.

[image]